# URLSessionDelegate functions not called for background upload on watchOS

Tags: swift, watchos, urlsession

I'm using a Series 6 emulator on watchOS7 and I'm trying to upload some JSON data to a remote server using an URLSession background task.  However the delegate functions are not being called so I cannot clean up any local data from the upload and handle any errors.  I got the original idea from my implementation from this WWDC video [WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10003/).  I've looked at many posts on the Internet but nothing I've tried seems to work.  Here is my code:

**UploadSession class**

```
class UploadSession: NSObject, Identifiable, URLSessionDelegate {

var backgroundTasks = [WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask]()

private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "my.app.watchextension")
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()

func enqueueBackgroundTask(idToken: String, uploadData: Data, url: URL) throws {
    //build the JSON object we want to send in this post request
    let tempDir = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    let localURL = tempDir.appendingPathComponent("throwaway")
    try? uploadData.write(to: localURL)
    
    //set up the URLRequest
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = K.Upload.httpPost
    request.setValue(K.Upload.jsonContent, forHTTPHeaderField: K.Upload.contentType)
    request.setValue("\(K.Upload.bearer)\(idToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: K.Upload.authorization)
    request.timeoutInterval = K.Upload.httpUploadTimeout
    
    //keep a reference to this class
    BackgroundURLSessions.shared.sessions["my.app.watchextension"] = self
    
    //create the upload task and kick it off
    let task = urlSession.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: localURL)
    task.earliestBeginDate = Date().advanced(by: 120)//when setting this to zero the upload runs straight away.
    task.resume()
}

func addBackgroundRefreshTask(_ task: WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask) {
    backgroundTasks.append(task)
}

//gets called when the task background task completes
func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    //PROBLEM. This delegate method is never called
    if let sessionId = session.configuration.identifier {
        
        //TODO delete any local data copies
        
        //set the session to nil so the system doesn't try to execute it again
        BackgroundURLSessions.shared.sessions[sessionId] = nil
    }
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
    }
}

//gets called if the background task throws an error
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
    //PROBLEM. This delegate method is never called
}
```

}

**BackgroundURLSessions class**

```
class BackgroundURLSessions: NSObject {
static let shared: BackgroundURLSessions = BackgroundURLSessions()
var sessions = [String: UploadSession]()

override private init() {
    super.init()
}
```

}

**Extension Delegate class**

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
for task in backgroundTasks {
    // Use a switch statement to check the task type
    switch task {
    case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
        // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
        if let session = BackgroundURLSessions.shared.sessions[urlSessionTask.sessionIdentifier] {
            session.addBackgroundRefreshTask(urlSessionTask)
        } else {
            urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    default:
        // make sure to complete unhandled task types
        task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
    }
}
```

}

Any help really appreciated as I'm really struggling to get this work and it's a vital part of the application.  Thanks.